# on the meaning of と云ったなり

Tags: grammar, meaning

this is a sentence in Natsume Sōseki's novel 門

「おい、好い天気だな」と話しかけた.
細君は、「ええ」と云ったなりであった。

my question is what is this なり here ?

Answer (score 2):

This なり is similar to [まま](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13551/5010) that adds the nuance of "remain unchanged" or "followed by nothing". The wife said ええ, and nothing followed. ～たなりだ is not as common as ～たままだ in modern Japanese. From 明鏡国語辞典:

> 接助
>
> ①《動詞などの連体形に付いて》ある動作の成立とほとんど同時に次の動作・作用が起こるときの、先行の動作を表す。「帰るなり部屋へ閉じこもってしまった」「一目見るなり病気だと分かった」
>
> **②《過去の助動詞「た」の連体形に付いて》ある動作の成立後に次の動作に移らずにそのままの状態が続くときの、先行の動作を表す。…まま。「坐りこんだなり動かない」「服を着たなり寝てしまった」**

Comment: so 、it basically means that she only answered with ええ

Comment: @lightofgold Basically yes, but the focus is on the silence after saying ええ.